# Call to webservice fails from Ubuntu, whereas it succeeds from Windows

Tags: networking, dns

I have a python piece of code which calls a SOAP webservice via SUDS library. If I use the name of the server in the webservice URL, the call fails from Ubuntu, saying that the server is Unknown, whereas it succeeds from Windows 11 (I have a dual-boot PC). I've verified that in both cases the ethernet card gets configured the same way by the DHCP server. Is there any reason for that behavior?
Thanks in advance, regards

Comment: Is the DNS info in both OS the same? As well please add the version of Ubuntu to your question, it often helps when trying to assist you.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.10, just upgraded to. DNS IP was the same in both cases.